# How do I convince the Typescript checker that a value is a specific subclass in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with the (relatively) new `checkJS` option enabled -- I'm writing Javascript, but this lets the Typescript engine do limited type checking.

I am looking up a DOM element using `querySelector` and accessing an element-specific property:

```
var img = document.querySelctor("#myImage");
img.src = "image.png";
```

This causes Code to flag the second line as a problem, since querySelector only returns an `Element` and the `.src` property is a member of `HTMLImageElement`.  In actual Typescript, I'd cast (coerce? assert?) the return value before accessing the property, but since this is vanilla Javascript it's not an option.  Is there any other way to avoid peppering my code with TS-specific control flags in the comments?

Comment: I haven't touched any typescript but I've seen `as` being a good keyword for your scenario.  `var img = document.querySelector("#myImage") as HTMLImageElement`

Comment: First of all, only use `var` if you know exactly about his `scoping`: better using `let` instead. Then, to answer your question, you should give a `type`to your variable `img` like `any`. `typescript` does not know what `type` he have when calling `querySelector`.

Comment: You can do it like this `let img = <any>document.querySelctor("#myImage");`

Comment: Just to be totally clear, I am writing plain JS (not TS), and packaging it with Babel / Webpack.  I need the *editor* to understand that this method that returns an `Element` will always, with the arguments I happen to pass, return the `HTMLImageElement` subclass, but I need my build tools to receive valid JS.

Comment: [Trackback to Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31590), I'm concerned that there won't be a fix for this other than to litter my code with `// @ts-ignore` :(

Answer (score 0):

An update from the Github issue I linked in the comments:

Today, there's no "good" way to solve it but you can use an explicit type check to shut up the compiler:

```
if (img instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
  img.src = "image.png";
}
```

You might know that the check can't possibly fail, but it makes the checker happy.  In future, the checker will support comment directives:

```
const el = /* @type {HTMLImageElement} */ (document.querySelector("#definitelyAnImage"));
```

This is in nightly builds today, so I'd expect to see it live in the July or August releases, but that's not official.